# Measure blood pressure with iphone

Tags: iphone, camera

Recently I came across this app "Instant Blood Pressure - Monitor Blood Pressure Using Only Your Phone by Aura Labs, Inc."
https://appsto.re/us/jWIYX.i which claims to measure your blood pressure just by using the camera of your iPhone. I also use a meditation app called Sattva which can measure my heart rate pretty accurately just by placing my finger against the camera.

Although the two applications are doing slightly different things (pressure vs heart rate), how does this technology work?

Comment: It recognizes the change of color of your skin when the blood pulses

Comment: Direct quote from the description.... "At this time, results may vary for different users and some users may experience inaccurate measurements. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very much doubt that you can measure blood pressure using the camera. Pulse is different. It measures the amount of red colour in the skin and finds the rate at which it changes. Blood pressure is different though.

The way it is measured by doctors is to apply pressure to the blood vessels and decrease it to the point where the blood can be heard pulsing and then again when it can't. Without knowing these pressures you cannot measure blood pressure (by definition).